# Getting the current directory name without trailing slash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been browsing around the web on how to get the name of the current directory the user is in on a website. This is what was most relevant:

```
function checkDir(theDir) {
    var loc = window.location.pathname;
    var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));

    if(dir == theDir)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

But this only works if there's a trailing slash.

To my surprise, there's not much information regarding this. Maybe it's just because of that it's an easy fix, I don't know.

How can I check the current directory without a trailing slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last directory in a path, split the path by `/`, then use `pop()` to get the last element:

```js
function checkDir(theDir) {
  var loc = window.location.pathname;
  var dir = loc.split('/').pop();
  console.log(loc);

  return dir == theDir;
}

console.log('js', checkDir('js'));
console.log('foo', checkDir('foo'));
```